# Update a whole table with mysqli and php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, html-table

I have created a page to list all users with their rights on the website. I used the code below to create and fill the table and it works great.

```
echo '<form method="post" id="detail" class="group" action="includes/setup_change.php?change=rights">';
echo '<div class="group">';
if (!empty($_GET['change'])) {
    if ($_GET['change'] == 'rights') { echo '<span class="message_alert success"><span class="icon success"></span><span class="text">' . _('Your password was successfully changed') . '.</span></span>'; }
}
echo '<h2>' . _('Change') . ' ' . _('rights') . '</h2>';
// select database
    mysqli_select_db( $mysqli, 'db_ccadmin' );
// check connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_errno > 0 ) {
    trigger_error( _('Database connection failed') . ': '  . $mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR );
}
// sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$res = $mysqli->query( $sql );
if( !$res ) {
    trigger_error( _('Wrong') . ' SQL: [' . $sql . ']. ' . _('Error') . ' : [' . $mysqli->error . ']' );
} else {
    echo '<table id="table_sort_no_search">';
    echo '<thead><tr>
            <th class="username">' . _('Username') . '</th>
            <th class="readonly">' . _('Read-only') . '</th>
            <th class="manage">' . _('Manage') . '</th>
            <th class="admin">' . _('Admin') . '</th>
        </tr></thead>'; 
    echo '<tbody>';
    // output query results
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>'; 
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="username" value="' . $row['username'] . '" readonly></td>';
        echo '<td><label><input type="radio" class="rights" name="rights_' . $row['username'] . '" value="1" ' . (isset($row['rights']) ? (($row['rights'] == '1') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ) : '') . '></label></td>';
        echo '<td><label><input type="radio" class="rights" name="rights_' . $row['username'] . '" value="2" ' . (isset($row['rights']) ? (($row['rights'] == '2') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ) : '') . '></label></td>';
        echo '<td><label><input type="radio" class="rights" name="rights_' . $row['username'] . '" value="3" ' . (isset($row['rights']) ? (($row['rights'] == '3') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ) : '') . '></label></td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    // free results to free up some system resources
    $res->free();
```

The trouble is updating the whole table in the database. I don't know how to do this. Is it even possible to update the whole table (as generated) at once? If yes, how?
What would be the code that I need to put in my setup_change.php?

It would be great if you could help me!

Comment: Look up [`UPDATE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to update, but this is how you can update (example):

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE birthday SET Manage = null");
```

Of course, this does not solve your problem, as there is infinite ways to update the whole table. What table do you want to update, what values do you want to set?

Comment: I generate a table from the database, using the code above. In the table I can set rights for every user. When hitting the submit button, I would like all the values in the whole table to be updated in the database.